# How to save a NSInteger?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, nsinteger

Heres what I've tried

```
 NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [prefs setInteger:HighScore forKey:@"integerkey"];
        [prefs synchronize];

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
HighScore = [prefs integerForKey:@"integerKey"];
```

Implicit conversion loses integer precision: `NSInteger` (aka `long`) to `int`.

Comment: I suspect HighScore is not an actual NSInteger, at least when fetching from the prefs...?

Comment: wool since I'm trying to run it on a 64 bit device I suspected it would be appropriate to put it as an NSinteger

Comment: `NSInteger` is probably a good choice here, however, somewhere you're trying to store the value from an `NSInteger` into an `int` which is not the same type. Which line is giving the warning/error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On 64-bit platforms, `NSInteger` is a 64-bit quantity, but `int` is only 32-bit.

I *assume* that you have declared

```
int HighScore;
```

so you can change that to

```
NSInteger HighScore;
```

or add an explicit cast

```
HighScore = (int)[prefs integerForKey:@"integerKey"];
```

to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to NSNumber because NSInteger isn't an object. And save that object in defaults.

Comment: However, [setInteger](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/setInteger:forKey:) would seem to take an NSInteger as a parameter, not an NSNumber.

Comment: oh okay let me try that :]